# File location of Service Worker affect the accessibility for registration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am trying to create a PWA with reactjs. There is no service worker when I use create-react-app so I created one myself.

The simplified file structure is this:

```
-public
    -index.html
    -manifest.json
    -**service-worker.js**
-src
    -index.js
    -serviceWorkerRegistration.js
```

The entry point of the app is index.js, which will import serviceWorkerRegistraion.js. Then serviceWorkerRegistration will run the following code:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    console.log("support service worker");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js") // Line A
        .then(reg => console.log("service worker registered", reg))
        .catch(err => console.warn("service worker registration failed", err));
}
else console.log("service worker not supported");
```

And the service worker is registered successfully.

---

However, if I move service-worker.js to the src directory and change the file name in Line A to "./service-worker.js", it seems service-worker.js cannot be found and throw an error with The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html') (which happens when the file cannot be found and a html file is returned instead)

Why the location of service-worker.js affect the accessibility for registrating service worker in this way? Is there any way I can access the file with service-worker.js living in the src directory?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related but I just banged my head and finally found a solve for myself so going to share. I didn't quite reproduce an error getting thrown (although I did not look) but I did notice that my serviceWorker updates were failing suddenly after doing a large project refactor where I was moving files around. Digging in the docs I found the following

https://web.dev/learn/pwa/service-workers/#scope

> Warning

> You should set the scope of your service worker as close to the root of your app as possible. This is the most common setup as it lets the service worker intercept all the requests related to your PWA. Don't put it inside, for instance, a JavaScript folder or have it loaded from a CDN.

once I moved both the `service-worker.ts` and the `serviceWorkerRegistration.ts` files back directly under `src/` thing started working again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).